# Spring Data Startup Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

How would I catch an exception thrown by Spring after failing to connect to the database during startup? I'd like to make the error message user-friendly.

For example, if the password isn't correct, the following is thrown:

```java
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "cikfedlekqbuk"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
...
```

Or if the format is incorrect, this is thrown:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://url:port
... Stack trace
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://url:port
... Stack trace
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://url:port
... Stack trace
```

The two possible solutions I've come across were using @ExceptionHandler or using AOP. Both failed however, because @ExceptionHandler is MVC specific and AOP wouldn't recognize the methods. Here's the example of a pointcut I've tried:

```java
@AfterThrowing(value="execution(* org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.*())", throwing="e")
```

I've also tried with `com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource` and others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the postgres connection string you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres
```